# Considerations for deploying TFS 2010 with Sharepoint 2007

Tags: sharepoint, tfs, sharepoint-2010

Our development team is making the move to TFS 2010 from VSS.   The company has an existing Sharepoint 2007 installation.   My understanding is that TFS can be integrated with Sharepoint.  I have a couple of questions concerning this new TFS installation:

1. Please confirm that Sharepoint is NOT a prerequisite for a TFS installation and TFS does not need to be integrated with Sharepoint.
2. Is an upgrade to Sharepoint 2010 required in order to integrate Sharepoint with TFS 2010?
3. What type of integration between TFS and Sharepoint is possible?
4. Which of the features from #3 are only available with Sharepoint 2010?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. MOSS is not a requirement, it will however install WSS if you prefer not to use an existing MOSS installation. A sharepoint enviroment (either installed with TFS or an existing environment) is needed, to host the project portals in (used to display reports etc.)
2. No, TFS 2010 still uses WSS 3.0 / MOSS
3. out of the box TFS comes with WSS, it can however use an existing sharepoint envronment to host the project portals in.
4. TFS2010 still uses MOSS / WSS 3.0

Comment: Does the WSS that came with TFS 2010 the same with a full install of Sharepoint server? If not, what's the difference?

Comment: Thanks for your helpful response.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the answers of your questions:

1. In case of TFS 2008 SharePoint was the prerequisite on TFS and it was installed with the TFS2008 setup, but in TFS 2010 it is not a prerequisite for TFS 2010 installation, we need to manually installed the Sharepoint server 2010. its better to installed the sharepoint 2010 before installation of TFS 2010.
2. You can use the SharePoint 2007 with TFS 2010, but it's better to installed the SharePoint 2010 with TFS 2010.
3. TFS uses the SharePoint for its documentation like Project Plan, Task creation, Change Request etc and many more. You can upload any document on SharePoint Portal using TFS and can share with these docs with the client of any one. There a lots of other usage of SharePoint with TFS but I cannot explain all here.
4. All the features are available in both SharePoint 2007 and 2010, but the main thing is TFS 2010 is more compatible with SharePoint 2010, and we have many more features are available in SharePoint 2010